# Regex does not match

Tags: regex

I need to catch the country. This is an example of the message

```
field1="text" field2="123.456" country="Netherlands" fieldx="text" country="United States" fieldy="more text"
```

When using this regex, It only matches Netherlands. It should match both countries

```
^.+\scountry=\"(\S+)\"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse HTML with regex...

Comment: The answer depends.  What coding language are you using?

Comment: `\S+` matches non-space characters. `country="United States"` clearly contains a space.

Answer (score 1):

The string `United States` contains a space, but in your capturing group you have `\S+`, which matches a string of anything *but* spaces.

I would suggest using `[^\"]+` (i.e. a string of anything but quotes) instead:

```
country=\"([^\"]+)\"
```

([demo](http://rubular.com/r/jBp5hMEmdE))

Comment: Seems to work aswell, solved it with country=\"(.*?)" however. Thank you for your effort. Message came from a Fortinet appliance, it's some kind of derivative from syslog messages

Answer (score 1):

The second country you want to match includes whitespace so it fails to match, `\S` matches any non-whitespace character. You can use a negated character class `[^ ]` here instead.

```
country="([^"]*)"
```